# Remove the element in the nested object of an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the below sample data which contains the array. I tried to unset or remove the nested object from the messages array.

## Sample Data:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51e98d196b01c2085c72d731"),

   "messages" : [ { "defaultId" :{
                           "_id" : ObjectId("520167056b01c20bb9eee987")

                                 },
                    "id" : ObjectId("520167056b01c20bb9eee988")

                  }

                ]

}
```

## Query:

```
db.rename_collection.update({"messages._id":{$exists: true}},
{$unset: {"messages.$.defauliId": {"_id": ""} }} )
```

Result: Nothing is coming - no error and no unset.

I have to perform some additional operations on the above data:
- I have to set "id" property name to "userId".
- Add new info as "id": "newInfo" (I hope i can use $addToSet)

Could you please look at my query? What might be the problem?

Comment: Should be "messages.id" in the query part ??

Answer (score 0):

According to your **sample data** you should use `messages.id` instead of `messages._id` and typo
`defaultId` instead of `defauliId`

so can try this one if your `messages` array **contains one object**

```
db.rename_collection.update({"messages.id":{$exists: true}},
    {$unset: {"messages.$.defaultId": {"_id": ""} }},{multi:true} )
```

also can use `{$unset: {"messages.$.defaultId": true }}` to remove `defaultId` object.

If your `messages` contains multiple object then above query will not update all `messages` object. Because currently **MongoDB** not allowed *positional operator* `$` to update all elements of an *array*. So to update all `messages` objects you can follow this process.

```
db.rename_collection.find({})
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.messages.forEach(function (message) {
      if (message.id) {
        delete message.defaultId;
      }
    });
    db.rename_collection.save(doc);
  });
```

Comment: I did not get any result even after correcting my query: Result:: {
 "ok" : 1,
 "nInserted" : 0,
 "nUpserted" : 0,
 "nMatched" : 1,
 "nModified" : 0,
 "nRemoved" : 0
}

Comment: should be working first query if `messages` contains one object. if multiple object in `messages` then can follow second process . can see updated answer @M.S.Naidu

Comment: Thank you @Shaish, Its working now, but actually I want to maintain "_id" value as it is and needs to change the name from "_id" to "userId".